# regex to find a substring

Tags: java, regex

I'm crawling some data from an ecommerce site.

The data can be..

```
Moto G (Black, with 16 GB)
Apple iPhone 5S (Gold, with 16 GB)
Apple iPhone 5S (Space Grey, with 16 GB)
```

I want the data in the following form:

```
Moto G 16
Apple iPhone 5S 16
Apple iPhone 5S 16
```

The product should contain the storage size if it is available in the original string.

My attempt in java:

```
str.replaceAll("(GB|gb|gB|Gb)|Gold|Silver|Space|dual|Dual|DUAL|sim|Sim|SIM|with|(^\\W*)|(\\?.*)|(( - \\w*).*)|((,).(^[0-9])*)|(\\((\\w*,*)*\\))|(\\(\\)*)|(\\)*)", "")
```

This doesn't work properly. and also It is hardcoded. Any help?

**UPDATE:** removed the last condition

Comment: Your first 3 lines have one pattern and the 4th line has another. I don't think its wise to use regex here.

Comment: The rule for shortening the string on the last line isn't clear. Could you develop?

Comment: check if this is what you're looking for  

    /(.+)(?=\([^)].+\s(\d+) GB\)|$)/g

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexp, write a small piece of code using strings to find the information you need in each line. Also, make sure that when the storage size is given, it's given in some pre-defined format which you understand correctly. Otherwise you might not be able to make a distinction between say storage size 16 and a device whose model contains the string 16.

Answer (score 1):

Here be the answer for the case where everything of interest / be removed is in parentheses.

```
result = str.replaceFirst("\\((?:.*?(\\d+)\\s*GB.*|.*)\\)", "$1"));
```

Replaces as follow:

- Find the outer parenthesis, and if in it there are a number of digits,
  followed by any amount of optional whitespace followed by GB, then capture
  the digits into group 1.
- otherwise do not capture any groups.
- replace the matched outer parenthesis with the value of optional group 1

Comment: However it would fail to remove the extra in the last condition before edit, where nothing was parenthesized

Comment: it is also replacing the storage size

Comment: Of course it is, replacing it by itself, `Moto G (Black, with 16 GB)` => `Moto G 16` as requested

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to handle this with one large regular expression. I suggest you start by decomposing the problem:

```
private static final Pattern MEMORY_SIZE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d+) GB");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> phones = Arrays.asList("Moto G (Black, with 16 GB)",
                                        "Apple iPhone 5S (Gold, with 16 GB)",
                                        "Apple iPhone 5S (Space Grey, with 16 GB)",
                                        "Nokia X Dual SIM Price");

    for (String phone : phones) {
        String memory = extractMemory(phone);
        phone = phone.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
        phone = phone.replaceAll("Dual SIM Price", "");
        String normalizedPhone = String.format("%s %s", phone.trim(), memory);
        System.out.println(normalizedPhone);
    }
}

private static String extractMemory(String phone) {
    Matcher memoryMatcher = MEMORY_SIZE_PATTERN.matcher(phone);
    if (memoryMatcher.find()) {
        return memoryMatcher.group(1);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Output:

```
Moto G 16
Apple iPhone 5S 16
Apple iPhone 5S 16
Nokia X
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect case for regular expressions but if you still want to use regular expressions than you need to use two patterns with an `OR` operator, something like this

```
    String str= "Moto G (Black, with 16 GB)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\(.*,.*[Ww]ith(.*)[Gg][Bb]\\)|(.*)Dual.*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if(m.matches()) {
            System.out.println((m.group(1)!=null?m.group(1):"")+(m.group(2)!=null?m.group(2):"")+(m.group(3)!=null?m.group(3):""));
    }
```

Hope this gives you a starting point and help you in getting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works for all but the last one; last one is given in different format.

```
sed -r -e 's:^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+).* ([0-9]+) GB.*:\1 \2:' < test.txt
```